# How to find config column in core_config_data table?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, system.xml

I want to add values to this field from "core_config_data" table, how do i identify it ?

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <section id="vsbridge_indexer_settings">
                <group id="catalog_settings" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <field id="product_attributes" translate="label comment" type="multiselect" sortOrder="102" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Product attributes to export</label>
                        <source_model>Divante\VsbridgeIndexerCatalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Attributes</source_model>
                        <backend_model>Divante\VsbridgeIndexerCatalog\Model\Config\Backend\Attributes</backend_model>
                        <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        <comment>Select which product attributes should be exported. Some attributes will be always exported: name, sku, price, status, url_path, url_key, visibility.</comment>
                    </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value will be save in this pattern:

```
section_id/group_id/field_id
```

Sot the identifier for any of the filed will follow this pattern

For direct query in your database you can use:

```
select * from core_config_data where path='*section_id/group_id/field_id'
```

In your case query will be:

```
select * from core_config_data where path='vsbridge_indexer_settings/catalog_settings/product_attributes'
```

On code level you need to follow this to fetch your data using this:

```
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ...
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $productAttributesConfig = $this->scopeConfig->getValue("vsbridge_indexer_settings/catalog_settings/product_attributes");
}
```